# Awk: retrive lines based on a range of columns of a file

Tags: awk

I want to retrieve lines which have a space character from character 83 + 16 characters and ignore all lines which have another character/string/integer in this range.

here is my file.txt:

```
7653903747235209876401            HGFDKJKK      98765435475237        caJHGFDSQ200                00779999        654321000704          2014100812204898764513165432
7653903747235209854311                 KJH      98765435475280             lkjUIHJ100808442700001298765432        654321009999          2014100812204898764513165432
7653903747235209854311                 BBB      98765435475280             lkjUIHJ100808442700001298765432        654321009999          2014100812204898764513165432
7653903747235209876401            GHJUYTHH      98765435475237        caJHGFDSQ200                00779999        654321000704          2014100812204898764513165432
```

here is my code and i want to add this condition to this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
var='^20141008'
awk -v var=$var '$1~/[01]1$/ && $7 ~ var'  file.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by  `column 83 + 16 columns` ?

Comment: the first 83 character plus 16=> range from 83 to 99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add another regex match to your current awk line:

```
$ awk -v var="$var" '$1~/[01]1$/ && $7 ~ var && substr($0,83,16) ~ /^ +$/'  file.txt
```

The check is that the substring containing 16 characters starting from character 83 matches the pattern. The pattern ensures that only spaces occur between the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

```
awk -v var="$var" '$1~/[01]1$/ && $7~var && /^.{82} {16}/' file.txt
```

Actually referring to `$7` can cause problems, as it seems that this in not a white-space separated list, but a COBOL like fixed width list. So I may reinterpret it into a single pattern using absolute positions:

```
var=20141008
awk -v var="$var" 'match($0,"^.{20}[01]1.{60} {16}.{38}"var)' file.txt
```

or the little bit shorter:

```
var=20141008
awk '/^.{20}[01]1.{60} {16}.{38}'"$var"'/' file.txt
```

In older gawk the `--posix` argument should be added to enable the interval regex.